# ReactJS - Export modules from main file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some React classes like this which I want to export:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

var Foo = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        foo1: PropTypes.string,
        foo2: PropTypes.number
    },
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            foo1: 'foo1',
            foo2: 2
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>Foo</div>
        );
    },
});

export default Foo;
```

But I want to call them from one file, so I created a `main.js` file in the same directory:

```
var Foo = require('./Foo');
var Foo2 = require('./Foo2');

export default { Foo, Foo2 };
```

In `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build-js', function() {
    return browserify('./src/main.js')
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['build-js']);
```

And the `package.json` specifies the main file:

```
"main": "dist/bundle.js"
```

Then, in a testing app, I want to use these components, so in `package.json` I added `main` as a dependency:

```
"main": "file:../../main"
```

And I try to call them from a page:

```
import { Foo } from 'main';
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './emptyFunction' from '/testing-react/node_modules/main/dist'

I can see that `bundle.js` has `var emptyFunction = require('./emptyFunction');` and some more `require` of files which actually doesn't exist. I'm a bit confused with this. I tried other combinations without success. Probably I'm doing something wrong when exporting from `main.js`, maybe because I'm exporting twice. Any idea?

**Edit:**

This seems to be related to `gulpfile.js`, since I tried using `browserify('./src/Foo.js')` insead of `browserify('./src/main.js')` with same results.

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137169/build-react-components-with-gulp-browserify-and-babel

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var Foo = require('./Foo');
var Foo2 = require('./Foo2');

export default { Foo, Foo2 };
```

to

```
export const Foo = require('./Foo');
export const Foo2 = require('./Foo2');
```

*Update*

Combining the `export /import` syntax with `require` in the same file might get messy. Consider not using `require` but `import`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The normal way of doing stuff is to import all dependencies directly in each module, and use browserify to package the entire thing in a bundle. So when you want to use `Foo` just add `import Foo from './myFooFile.js'`. Also, when you use `export default`, that resource is imported without using curly brackets.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to create a bundled distribution of the `Foo` components.