# Build React components with Gulp, Browserify and Babel

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I've created a React component and I want to distribute a built-in version (built with gulp) of this component, so in `gulpfile.js` I have:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build-js', function() {
    return browserify('./src/Foo.js')
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['build-js']);
```

In `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
}
```

And these are the dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7"
}
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
  "babelify": "^7.2.0",
  "browserify": "^13.0.0",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "react": "^0.14.7",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
  "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
}
```

When I run `gulp build` (after `npm install`) `build.js` file is created under `/dist`, but when I try to use this component from other React app I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module ' ./emptyFunction'.

If I dig into this file (`build.js`), I can see these lines:

```
var emptyFunction = require('./emptyFunction');
...
var camelize = require('./camelize');
```

These files does not exist under `./dist`, so the error is thrown when I try to build the new React app calling the component:

```
import Foo from 'my-components-in-node-modules';
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**:

As I can see, the weird *requires* come from requiring React within the component file:

```
var React = require('react');
// or import React from 'react';

class Foo extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {...};
    static defaultProps = {...};
    render() {...}
}
export default Foo;
```

If I remove `var React = require('react');` those *requires* (emptyFunction, camelize) disappear, and the error is `React is not defined`, obviously.

**Edit2:**

As @JMM suggests, I should have the dependencies (React in my case) in the  `dist` folder, but how should I achieve it? What if my component has more dependencies? I thought that I just had to have the dependencies defined in `package.json`.

**Edit3:**

I finally realized that I don't need `browserify`, just `gulp-babel`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('bundle', bundle);

function bundle () {
  gulp.src('./src/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}

gulp.task('build', ['bundle']);
```

And that's all. The full example is here: [react-svg-components](https://github.com/msalsas/react-svg-components).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JMM When I try to use the component from a react app, gulp throws an error `Error: Cannot find module ' ./emptyFunction'`.

Comment: The error is at compile time or at run time? You get a single file `dist/bundle.js`, right? All of the dependencies should be in that bundle. So the `require()` calls you're highlighting should resolve to something in the bundle.

Comment: @JMM At run time. Yes, I get a single file `dist/bundle.js`. Ok, so if all of the dependencies should be in that bundle, how to handle this? I just need React as dependency.

Comment: Ok, so that's not gulp throwing an error. I don't know -- it's unclear from the example why you're getting that error.

Comment: @JMM Well, it's a gulp error when I try to use the components from other project which also use gulp. But essentially, the problem is that I can't require React from the component. How can I then distribute a build-in React component which, of course, requires React?

Comment: @JMM I've edited my question. Maybe it's clearer now...

Comment: Are you browserifying a component, then browserifying an app that has the browserified component in its dependency graph? That's what it sounds like you're saying now and that would explain the problem. If you can confirm that's the case I'll explain it.

Comment: @JMM Exactly. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your most recent explanation, you probably need to do something like this when browserifying your component:

```js
browserify('./src/Foo.js')
// Note this call:
.external("react")
.transform(babelify)
.bundle()
```

The problem has nothing to do with gulp. I also don't know how / when you were getting the run time error you described in the comments. Based on your latest information, the problem is that you're creating bundle `A` with browserify, then creating bundle `B` with browserify, with `A` in its dependency graph, and browserify is trying to resolve relative `require()`'s that are already bundled in `A`. Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078425/browserifying-libraries-that-were-themselves-browserified-relative-paths-error/28176927#28176927) for how to deal with that:

Here are a few options:

- Run [derequire](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire) on bundle `A` before consuming / publishing.
- Try browserifying your app like so:

  ```js
  browserify({
    entries: ['./entry'],
    noParse: ['my-components-in-node-modules'],
  })
  ```

  If it doesn't work, try an absolute path (`require.resolve('my-components-in-node-modules')`).
- Minify bundle `A` before consuming it.

A more detailed explanation of that issue can be found in [substack/node-browserify#1151](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/1151).

I'm not sure bundling React with your component is the way to go. I'm not sure, but I think in that case people must peer depend on React (implicitly or explicitly). Including React in the bundle means different components would be trying to use different instances of React, which may cause you problems, and would definitely bloat the `node_modules` directory for each component that does it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if this makes sense for my case. My component is like the first question's edition ( a bit more...). Just need React for defining my component. Everyone who wants to install and use this component has to have React installed, so the component would use the same instance of React that the app using this component. I'm having trouble to make me clear :P I've tried what you said, but doesn't work, derequire doesn't change anything, neither the second option, and the last one throws me an error (with uglify): `TypeError: file.isNull is not a function`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a new suggestion. It's difficult to fully understand what you're doing though.

Comment: Well, I've achieved to make it work with a little hack. I've pushed my changes to Github because it can already be used. This is the repo: https://github.com/msalsas/react-svg . I would also want to export all components from `src/react-svg.js`, but this is other story. The hack consist in run gulp without the requires methods, and then add them manually to `build.js`. Also removing the first and last lines (it's explained in `gulpfile.js`). Thank you for your great help :)

Comment: I took a look at your repo. Did you try the `.external("react")` call? That'll probably do the trick and be much cleaner and prevent you from having to manually fuss with things.

Comment: Half worked. I still have to remove the first and last lines of `build.js`: `(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u)...` and `},{"react":"react"}]},{},[1]);` respectively. Otherwise I get this runtime error: `bundle.js:88399 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what's going on off the top of my head -- something's not right. That line number and error message suggest that React is still being included in your bundle.

Comment: Great! Finally worked with your PR (https://github.com/msalsas/react-svg/pull/1/commits/b36c354448417b75ee7d493acc6fba45770256a7). I've just published the repo at npm as `react-svg-components` and `npm install react-svg-components` already works. Thank you!

Comment: And renamed in Github. Didn't know I could do that. https://github.com/msalsas/react-svg-components